# FB send popup box position

Tags: positioning, send, fbml, xfbml

Is there a way to position the popup box of the FB send button?

I've seen a "workaround" with additional CSS properties and tried it but it seems to be "cheesy" and not a good solution. FB developers pages has no reference to this so I presume that this feature is not contemplated! 
The only thing that I can say is "What the hell are these FB guys thinking?!" - because let's say that I'm using the button at the bottom or the right of a page. If I click the "send" button the box pops up below the button and messes up all the page layout! Wouldn't it be smart to have a property similar to "position=[top|topLeft|center|whatever...]"??? How come nobody thought of this? Am I the only one to use FB buttons at the bottom of page?

Maybe I'm missing something and FB dev guys already took care of this (if that's case sorry if I consider you dumb regarding this question) if not IS THERE A WAY TO DO IT?

Thank you for any help and cheers.
(p.s. not trying to offend anyone, it's just one of those hair pulling issues :P)